# Why we can't majorate it $\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{y^{2}}(x-\frac{1}{y})^{2}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{y^{2}}(x-\frac{1}{y})^{2}}dx$, where $0 < y < 1$. It's easy to show that for $y = 1$ integral majorating and it's equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-x^{2})dx$. But the task said that we can't do that.

Why we can't majorate it by integral doesn't depend of $y$?

Comment: You have a function of $y$ which is only defined for $y\in (0,1) $. So you cannot choose $y=1$ as the maximizer.

Comment: @Shashi using $sup$ we can use majorate it.

Comment: @Shashi my bad , add "-"

Comment: What's the context here, you want to show convergence of the integral? You want to solve it?

Comment: Actually the task is : prove that uniformly convergent integral couldn't be majorate by integral doesn't depend of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because
$$
\sup_{y\in(0,1)}\exp\left[-{1\over y^2}\left(x-{1\over y}\right)^2\right]=1,
$$
attained for $y=1/x$.

Comment: That means that it's not uniformly convergent?

Comment: Not necessarily, as far as I remember.

Comment: but why is it a problem?

Comment: How did you get the upper bound shown in your question?

Comment: I guess it means that function can be majorate by $e^{-(x-1)^{2}}$

Comment: Of course, but unfortunately that estimate is not true. The reason is explained in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68983/discussion-between-openspace-and-aretino).